# Why would same command run by .bashrc and .bash_login produce different outputs?

Tags: bash

I am using Ubuntu Linux 16.04

> (Linux 4.15.0-122-generic #124~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 15 16:08:36
> UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)

I have dual monitors on i3-wm and I run the following command to configure my two monitors.

```
#dual monitor
xrandr --output DVI-I-1  --mode 1920x1080 --pos 1920x0 --output HDMI-1 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0
```

When I run the above command on a simple terminal or include the same in my .bashrc file, my monitors get configured well.

However, if I place the same on my .bash_login or even in .bash_profile it does not work and my monitors do not get configured. But its the same command. I am confused as to why my unix like machine behaves differently. My guess is that these two files are executed by the system under different circumstances. But Can anyone shred more light?

Comment: **tl;dr;** You better put those `xrandr` command in some `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/*` file or in your `~/.xsessionrc` if it's sourced from there (go check). Neither `~/.bashrc` nor `~/.bash_profile` is guaranteed to be sourced when you log in via the GUI. Which files are sourced by bash when starting up is a very complex and quirky matter, depending on whether its argv[0] starts with a dash, what your distro is, etc. *Most of it* is documented in its manpage though, so if you're interested, go read it there.

Comment: Or if you don't use a Display Manager (DM) you should put `xrandr` command inside `~/.xinitrc`.

Comment: If ~/.bash_profile exists, then ~/.bash_login is ignored. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. I can confirm that .bash_profile doesnt work. As highlited by @user414777. However, I wonder why developers made it that way. I fixed this issue by placing the same command as "exec" item in my i3wm config.